# Issues Connecting to Local IIS ASP.NET site from Android Emulator

Tags: android, asp.net, iis, android-emulator, eclipse-adt

I have tried researching and tried some of the solution; however, I am not getting the connection to work.  The purpose is to connect to a sample ASP.NET website called HelloHTML5 that would have an HTML file named "Home.html".  From then on, I will edit the page accordingly.

- I am running VS 2013 in admin mode.
- Enabled all IIS features under "Programs and Features" as well as the separate IIS Hostable Web Core feature.
- Under the project's "Properties" within the "Web" tab under the
  "Servers" section I have it set to "Local IIS" which in turn displays
  the "Project URL" as so "`http://localhost/HelloHTML5`"(without
  quotations marks)
- I have set "Home.html" as the start page.

I can get the "Home.html" webpage to display on any web browser; however, I cannot get it to display on a Android Emulator.

- I am running the ADT version of Eclipse in admin mode and without.
- I open the AVD Manager and start the emulator.
- The emulator loads to the home screen.
- Within the emulator browser I enter the given

  1. The local ip address (IPv4):   `http://169.254.00.00/hellohtml5/home.html`
  2. `http://169.254.00.00/hellohtml5/`
  3. `http://169.254.00.00/hellohtml5`
  4. Other variations as well

Eventually I get the "Webpage not Available" message on the Android Emulator.

This is probably excessive information; however, for the sake of being specific:

1. I am running the webpage via VS 2013 by selecting view in "Google Chrome".
2. I am running an Android Emulator with API19.

Please advice if any more information is needed to resolve this issue.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried connecting to `http://10.0.2.2` ? See more here: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: Thanks.  Replacing that with the local ip address did the trick for me.  Thanks as well for the link to the source.